# Is EV3 Device Manager still active?

Tags: ev3

Link to https://ev3manager.education.lego.com/ is broken - will this be fixed?

Comment: This sounds like a question for LEGO Education customer support.

Comment: Where did you find this URL?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

As of April 2019, The EV3 Device Manager is active. However, if you have not downloaded the Device Manager to your computer, it will not function. Also, make sure that your EV3 is properly connected to your computer with a USB that can transfer information.